# How to test if given variable contains a valid html element?

Tags: javascript, htmlelements

That is such with tag name and attributes so then I can safely use for example `hasAttribute`, `tagName` and other similar methods.

(My question is for a method of positively asking for html element, not for example ruling out all possibilities like string, number, some kind of other object etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check if it is an instance of `HTMLElement`

```
if (varName instanceof HTMLElement){
   // do what you want with the node
}
```